# Edit Textmate syntax highlighting?

Tags: textmate

I have recently begun working with Objective-C in Textmate and noticed that the syntax highlighting is rather poor (a comment is the exact same color as a variable declaration).
I've never done syntax highlighting changes in Textmate and I'm having trouble figuring out how to correctly modify it.
For example the scope of a comment in an Objective-c file is:
source.objc.iphone
meta.implementation.objc
meta.scope.implementation.objc
meta.function-with-body.objc

but changing the colors on that changes alot more than just comments.

Does anyone know of a good place to start learning how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check the scope of your current cursor with ^ + Shift + P or Bundles > Bundle Development > Show Scode.
After you know the scope, you can create / change the color of it.
If the comment is not detected by the language grammar, you have to extend it. See the documentation for further information:
http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#language_grammars